# How can I get my image to stop repeatedly randomly generating co-ordinate boundary values?

Tags: java, game-development, slick2d

I'm creating a game in Java using the Slick2D library, and I'm a real beginner with this stuff.

I've been trying to get the image object I've created to randomly generate on the screen, which works, except it keeps randomly generating the co-ordinates for the image on loop. 
I want it to randomly generate once until another object touches it in which case it disappears and another instance of the same image object generates in a random position.

So far I've tried creating random objects for the x and y co-ordinates of the image.

```
    Image enemy;
    int enemyX = 800;
    int enemyY = 500;
    int RandomX;
    int RandomY;

public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException {
enemy = new Image("C:\\Users\\User\\IdeaProjects\\Slick2D\\src\\main\\resources\\enemy.png");
}

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        background.draw();
        blobfish.draw(RandomX, RandomY);
        enemy.draw(RandomX, RandomY);
        ninja.draw(characterX, characterY);
        g.drawString("X pos: " + characterX + "\nY pos: " + characterY, 400, 200);

        Random enemyX = new Random();
        Random enemyY = new Random();
        RandomX = enemyX.nextInt(1500);
        RandomY = enemyY.nextInt(1000);

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) {
        enemy.startUse();
}
```

No error messages. However I want it to generate just once but instead it generates so many times so it looks like it's flickering on the page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "generate just once"? You're explicitly moving it to a random location on each `render`, if that's not what you want to do, move that code out of `render`. Unrelated, but I'd stick w/ Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're updating `RandomX` and `RandomY` every time that you render your image, instead of only updating them when the enemy is touched. You usually don't want to update state inside of a render function, for the reason that it can be called many times a second. Instead, you have a recurring event handler (e.g. Timer) to handle state updates, and render state immutably inside a rendering method.

I've made some quick pseudocode of what you might want instead:

```
    Image enemy;
    int enemyX = 800;
    int enemyY = 500;
    Random random = new Random();
    int RandomX = random.nextInt(1500);
    int RandomY = random.nextInt(1000);

...

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        //draw things
        ...
        Point enemyLoc = game.getEnemy().getLocation();
        enemy.draw(enemyLoc.x, enemyLoc.y);
}
//UPDATE FUNCTION
public void ???(game, ???) {
    ...
    //update OUTSIDE of render function
    if(game.getEnemy().isTouched()) {
        game.getEnemy().setLocation(random.nextInt(1500), random.nextInt(1000));
    }
    ...
}
```